# get contents from div class span from other website

Tags: php, file-get-contents, getelementbyid

I am trying to get the contents from span, class, div  from external other domain to mine personal website. The source code of the website www.example.com is

```
    <div id="h_gold" class="h_metal">
      <div class="hm_inside">
        <div class="hm_title">Gold</div>
        <span class="arr_price_down">- 13.42 <img src="images/downarrow.jpg" alt="down" /></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="hm_cad">USD</div>
        <div class="hm_bottom">
          <div> Bid<br />
            <span>$1,749.20</span> </div>
          <div class="ask"> Ask<br />
            <span>$1,750.20</span> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .hm_bottom-->
      </div>
      <!-- hm_inside-->
    </div>
    <!-- h_metal-->
    <div id="h_silver" class="h_metal">
      <div class="hm_inside">
        <div class="hm_title">Silver</div>
        <span class="arr_price_down">- 0.54 <img src="images/downarrow.jpg" alt="down" /></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="hm_cad">USD</div>
        <div class="hm_bottom">
          <div> Bid<br />
            <span>$33.40</span> </div>
          <div class="ask"> Ask<br />
            <span>$33.50</span> </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .hm_bottom-->
      </div>
      <!-- hm_inside-->
    </div>
    <!-- h_metal-->
```

I have a problem here.. i tried  the following code.. but it doesnt loop, I only get the contents from the first < div class="hm_bottom" > , rests are not in the output,

```
    <?php
    function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = " ".$string;
        $ini = strpos($string,$start);
        if ($ini == 0)
            return "";
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string,$ini,$len);
    }
    $data = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/ajax.php?metal_cur=USD");

    $pricediv = get_string_between($data, '<div class="hm_bottom">', '</span>');
    $pricetext = strip_tags($pricediv);
    echo $pricetext;
    ?>
```

Secondly, i searched stachoverflow again, i found one solved, but doesnt perfectly matches my needs. the output is kinda okay, but i just want numerical data from the output to be placed in the particular div id  i define.

```
    <?php 
    $page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/ajax.php?metal_cur=USD');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($page);
    $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach($divs as $div) {
        // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
        // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
        if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'hm_bottom') {
             echo $div->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

the above code is from second search from stackoverflow

Comment: I want $1,749.20, $1,750.20 etc .... such numbers from the output generated to be put in in divs like <li><?php echo $output_1;?></li>...<li><?php echo $output_2;?></li> that would result<li>$1,749.20</li>, <li>$1,750.20</li>

Comment: Does the target of your search want/allow you to re-use/scrape their content? It's kinda douchy to steal other people's work, and possibly illegal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [str_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [file_get_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) as the case may be

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$amounts = array();
foreach ( $html->find("div[class=hm_bottom] span") as $span ) {
    $amount = trim($span->plaintext);
    if (strpos($amount, "\$") === 0)
        $amounts[] = $amount;
}

var_dump($amounts);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '$1,749.20' (length=9)
  1 => string '$1,750.20' (length=9)
  2 => string '$33.40' (length=6)
  3 => string '$33.50' (length=6)
```

Comment: I tried ,, but gives an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_get_html() in C:\xampp\htdocs\forex\6.php on line 2

Comment: I have edited question above.. and mentioned the try i made.. can you please have a look

Comment: Since you are working with URL .. it should be `file_get_html` not `str_get_html` .. its

Comment: instead of getting the out put like  array
  0 => string '$1,749.20' (length=9)
  1 => string '$1,750.20' (length=9)
  2 => string '$33.40' (length=6)
  3 => string '$33.50' (length=6), can you help me out for something like this.... <li><?php echo $array0;?></li>....<body><li>$1,749.20</li> .. <li><?php echo $array1;?></li>....ie <li>$$1,750.20</li></body>

Comment: You can do something like this